# Problemas mostrando mensaje al ejecutar una clase

Tags: php

Tengo este código que recibe el ***usuario*** y la ***clave***, ejecuto el método `cambiar()` en mi clase `UsuarioDAO()`.

```
$usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO(); 
$usuarioDAO->cambiar($_SESSION['usuario'], $_POST['clave']);
header('Location: index.php');
```

La clase `cambiar()` solo realiza una actualización.
Cómo hago para mostrar un mensaje que diga: `"Proceso OK"`?

He intentado hacer esto:

```
if( $usuarioDAO->cambiar($_SESSION['usuario'], $_POST['clave']) ){
    echo "OK";
}
```

Pero no ingresa al `if`.

Este es el método `cambiar()`.

```
public function cambiar($user, $pass) {
    try {
            $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET pass = :pass WHERE user = :user";
            $bd = new ConexionDB();
            $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam('pass', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die ('No se puede ejecutar la consulta);
        }
}
```

Comment: Deberias agregar el metodo `cambiar()`

Comment: Acabo de agregarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu `if` nunca se va a ejecutar, pues en el método `cambiar`, tienes `return;`, haciendo que el método no devuelva nada, cosa que se evalúa como `false`; por consecuencia, el condicional nunca dará `true`.

Lo que puedes hacer para solucionarlo es cambiar `return;` por `return true;` para que el condicional se ejecute, pues recibe una sentencia verdadera.

```php
public function cambiar($user, $pass) {
    try {
            $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET pass = :pass WHERE user = :user";
            $bd = new ConexionDB();
            $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam('pass', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die ('No se puede ejecutar la consulta');
        }
}
```

Arreglando esto, el condicional está bien planteado y debería ejecutarse con normalidad.

Comment: Cierto!, no me había percatado de eso.